# mysql create view from another view which do not exist yet

Tags: mysql

I export DDL into script file from existing db, and create database from script files.
Now each view or table is stored as seperate file to keep tracking changes.
Now there are two views (v_a and v_b). v_a is based v_b.
For example, in in v_a,

```
select v_b join ...
```

Script files are executed according to file name, and v_a is executed before v_b.
When v_a is executed and v_b doesn't exist in db. Mysql reports error.
How can let mysql to ignore this checking?

Answer (score 0):

rename your views so that is create before v_a

so `v_a  ==> v_a2` and `v_b  ==> v_a1`

A view needs a [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html) so that you can not check if INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS contains already v_b

Comment: this solution works, but needs to change application code. This needs too much effort.

Comment: when you have the sql files stored in one folder you can search all files and repace it quite easy with pspad or the most other text editirs, if you quite fit in Vb ent you can write in short time a programm which makes it for you.